# How to "roll up" rows on matching column data and create new columns for non-matching data in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for direction on how to "roll up" or combine rows in a database that match on specific column values and create new columns for data that doesn't match. I am only looking for direction and not an exact solution. I am using SSMS 2014.

For example, I have a query that outputs a dataset like this:

```
       fld1   fld2   fld3   fld4   fld5
---------------------------------------
row1    1      2      3      4     text1
row2    1      2      3      4     text2
row3    1      2      3      4     text3
```

I would like to manipulate output to this:

```
       fld1    fld2    fld3    fld4    fld5    fld6    fld7
------------------------------------------------------------
row1    1       2       3       4      text1   text2   text3
```

Again, I am only looking for direction, e.g. look into using PIVOT or FOR XML or RECURSIVE CTE, and not an exact solution since I am still learning. Thanks.

Comment: Since you're learning, and you just _"looking for direction"_, then I'll give you a hint: `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Sami I should have been more specific and state that fld5 are text values in my real-world case, so I don't think aggregate functions will help. I edited my original post to reflect correctly. I did look at GROUP BY ROLLUP which I foresee being helpful in the future so thanks for the hint. I ended up doing a self-join on the table to get the output I needed. Not sure if that is the best method though. I would love to hear other people's opinions/solutions.

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample data

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, MAX(Col5) Col5
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (1, 2, 3, 4, 'text1'),
  (1, 2, 3, 4, 'text2'),
  (1, 2, 3, 4, 'text3')
) T(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
GROUP BY Col1,
         Col2,
         Col3,
         Col4;
```

Will returns:

```
+------+------+------+------+-------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5  |
+------+------+------+------+-------+
|    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 | text3 |
+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

Comment: I still can't get the desired output with the extra columns using this method. Output needs to have additional columns (col6, col7) with the corresponding values (text2, text3). Col 5 should be 'text1'